# Dynamic react routes from JSON object

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, router

I am new to React and trying to learn the react-router. I can loop through the JSON object using the map method. But I am struggling to find a way to display the component based on each iteration. Like if the name is displayed, I want to display another array of objects in that particular iteration. I tried looking at the switch but I can't understand. Please help!!

```js
render() {
       return this.props.topic.map(t => (
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to={`${t.name}`}>{t.name}</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            ));

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch> 
         }
```

This is the JSON object

```
topics = [
    {
      name: 'React Router',
      id: 'react-router',
      description: 'Declarative, component based routing for React',
      resources: [
        {
          name: 'URL Parameters',
          id: 'url-parameters',
          description: "URL parameters are parameters whose values are set 
          dynamically in a page's URL. This allows a route to render the same 
          component while passing that component the dynamic portion of the 
          URL so it can change based off of it.",
          url: 'https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/'
        },
        {
          name: 'Programmatically navigate',
          id: 'programmatically-navigate',
          description: "When building an app with React Router, eventually 
           you'll run into the question of navigating programmatically. The 
            goal of this post is to break down the correct approaches to 
           programmatically navigating with React Router.",
          url: 'https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically- 
         navigate/'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'React.js',
      id: 'reactjs',
      description: 'A JavaScript library for building user interfaces',
      resources: [
        {
          name: 'React Lifecycle Events',
          id: 'react-lifecycle',
          description: "React Lifecycle events allow you to tie into specific 
          phases of a component's life cycle",
           url: 'https://tylermcginnis.com/an-introduction-to-life-cycle- 
           events-in-react-js/'
        },
        {
          name: 'React AHA Moments',
          id: 'react-aha',
          description: "A collection of 'Aha' moments while learning React.",
          url: 'https://tylermcginnis.com/react-aha-moments/'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Functional Programming',
      id: 'functional-programming',
      description: 'In computer science, functional programming is a 
      programming paradigm—a style of building the structure and elements of 
       computer programs—that treats computation as the evaluation of 
      mathematical functions and avoids changing-state and mutable data.',
      resources: [
        {
          name: 'Imperative vs Declarative programming',
          id: 'imperative-declarative',
          description: 'A guide to understanding the difference between 
          Imperative and Declarative programming.',
          url: 'https://tylermcginnis.com/imperative-vs-declarative- 
         programming/'
        },
        {
          name: 'Building User Interfaces with Pure Functions and Function 
          Composition',
          id: 'fn-composition',
          description: 'A guide to building UI with pure functions and 
         function composition in React',
          url: 'https://tylermcginnis.com/building-user-interfaces-with-pure- 
        functions-and-function-composition-in-react-js/'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```